# Laravel : Passing data from cart to checkout page

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am working on shopping cart, Currently passing the cart details like, Product price and quantity to checkout page, So on checkout i will be able to save data to another table like `purchased_items` etc.

I am passing data from cart page to checkout page by hidden input fields, There i am passing again the values to checkout view hidden fields so that i will be able to get that data into checkout method to save them to DB.

The issue is that i am passing arrays because the products and its quantities are in array.

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="{!!  !! $products !!}">
<input type="hidden" name="product_quantity[]" class="product_total_quantity" value="{!! $product_quantity !!}">
```

Its giving me :

> Array to string conversion

What will be a good way to tackle this ?

Comment: Pass you cart around in session instead

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to work correctly you need to create a single input per array entry:

```
 @foreach ($products as $product)
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="{!! $product !!}">
 @endforeach
 @foreach ($product_quantity as $q) 
     <input type="hidden" name="product_quantity[]" class="product_total_quantity" value="{!! $q!!}">
 @endforeach
```

When this is passed to the server then `\Input::get('product_id')` (or equivalently product_quantity) will contain your array again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{!! json_encode($products) !!}">
<input type="hidden" name="product_quantity" class="product_total_quantity" value="{!! json_encode($product_quantity) !!}">
```

Then you can get the array with `json_decode(\Input::get('field_name'))`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier if you save your products in a session or cookie?

```
Session::put('products', $product); // create a session
Session::push('products', $newProduct); // add a product to the array
$products = Session::get('products'); // read the products array
```